# What is the flaw in my algorithm for determining how many letter replacements one string needs to be an anagram of another string?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I've been staring at this for a half hour and can't figure out where I'm going wrong! I'm getting obviously incorrect answers for `count` in some of the test cases. I've tested every subroutine of the program and it works as expected. So WTF?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution
{    
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int T = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for(int t = 0; t < T; ++t)
        {

            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            if(str.Length % 2 == 1) // str couldn't be split into halves
            {
                Console.WriteLine(-1);
                continue;
            }
            // determine how many replacements s1 needs to be an anagram of s2
            int n = str.Length / 2;
            string s1 = str.Substring(0, n);
            string s2 = str.Substring(n, n);
            int[,] counter = new int[26,2]; // counter[i,j] will be the # of occurences of the i-th letter
                                            // of the alphabet in string sj
            int ascii_a = (int)'a'; 
            for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                counter[(int)s1[i] - ascii_a, 0] += 1;
                counter[(int)s2[i] - ascii_a, 1] += 1;
            }

            // sum difference of occurences in each letter, and divide sum by 2
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                count += Math.Abs(counter[i, 0] - counter[i, 1]);
            }
            count /= 2; 

            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Test input:

```
aaabbb
ab
abc
mnop
xyyx
xaxbbbxx
```

My output:

```
3
0
-1
0
0
1
```

Expected output:

```
3
1
-1
2
0
1
```

Comment: Could you, please, explain the expected output? Why, `ab` -> `1`, but `mnop` -> `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s2 is assigned as:

```
string s2 = str.Substring(n, n);
```

and I'm guessing you want to use:

```
string s2 = str.Substring(n, str.Length);
```

I think that should fix the problem you're having, but your current output is weirdly accurate for the first input